# Rpi B USB Not Working

Tags: usb, hardware

I have an early pi B 256 MB RAM on which the USB & maybe the ethernet sockets are dead, as I can't get access I'm not sure.
When I power up the OS seems OK (Raspbian & OSMC). The wired mouse & keyboard & the wireless ones work well on my other pi 3 and other PCs etc.

So can I use the old pi for any other purpose?
Could I operate it via SSH (of which I have absolutely no knowledge or understanding) or maybe couple it to my pi 3 to boost performance?

Comment: `Could I operate it via SSH` - definitely not if  `the ethernet sockets are dead`

Comment: You could use it for a project which only makes use of GPIO pins. Otherwise, it's practically useless.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Raspberry PI via SSH is quite easy and is explained [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/unix.md) for example.

Your question regarding boosting up performance isn´t that easy to answer. Depending on your application you are using, you could build something (here is a nice [article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/build-your-own-supercomputer-out-of-raspberry-pi-boards/) about that). But it seamed to be that you are more a home user, so a cluster isn´t that useful for most of the home users.

P.S.
By the way I would try to reinstall it fully (you can find many articles via google, here is [one](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/linux/89-from-0-to-raspberry-pi-start-with-raspberry-pi.html) as an example), I think that something might be not OK on the OS. If USB is fully broken you can also install something like [KODI](https://kodi.tv/) on it and use the KODI app on your mobile device to use it. Then you can connect the broken PI to your TV so that it can be useful here without the need to use USB (but need a LAN cable connected).

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Please forgive the delay in replying but I was hospitalised!! But am OK now thanks to the NHS.

Comment: This is a continuation of the previous (finger trouble I'm afraid!!) I've reinstalled Raspbian and it boots OK but still no USB and probably no ethernet either. So two more questions 1. Dimitry says "You could use it for a project which only makes use of GPIO pins". More information on this would be appreciated please. 2. Could I bypass the circuitry and solder a USB socket on a flying lead directly onto the PCB and access the OS that way? I'm not too good on computers but OK at soldering. And there's nothing to loose.